# how to start/restart fastcgi process?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I'm running nginx, and fastcgi to run a wordpress blog.

After a while of running, I am getting 502 bad gateway errors.   If i reboot the server things work fine.

Other sites that are running on nginx are not effected (they are not php based), so I just figured out it must be the fastcgi process after looking at the log files saying the upstream client 127.0.0.1 is not responding.

How to I restart this?  Is there a special log file for this fastcgi process?

Answer (score 10):

It depends of the Distro/Type but it is probably:

```
service php-fpm restart
or
service php5-fpm restart
```

Anyway restarting service is not a solution, you should find the problem why do the upstream is not responding. You may provide some logs to clarify the issue.

Comment: I use Docker's "php:7.4-fpm" image; I am getting "unrecognized service." error. I tried:
php-fpm, php5-fpm, php7-fpm, php7.0-fpm, php7.4-fpm (none work)

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the install:

- find init.d script: ls -al /etc/init.d/*php*
- look /usr/bin/php-fastcgi: ls -al /usr/bin/php-fastcgi
- look /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi(if exist '/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -u www-data -f /usr/bin/php5-cgi' to start, 'killall spawn-fcgi' to stop)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu every site have a process in

```
/etc/init.d/php-fcgi-domain-com-br
```

So, to restart a PHP domain proccess type:

```
sudo service php-fcgi-domain-com-br restart
```

Comment: this worked for me